# automatically call delete before updating pointer

Tags: c++11

As I'm not a developer I'm sure this is a keyword research problem more than anything else.

Considering

```
class A
{
public:

B* myBpointer;
[...]
}


class B
{
 [...]
}
```

and a simple snippet:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
 A myA;

 while(1)
 {
    if(myA.myBpointer)delete myA.myBpointer;
     myA.myBpointer = new B;
     [...]
 }
return 0;
}
```

Is there in c++ a better way to declare myBpointer to avoid to check if the pointer is null before actually assigning it if not or deleting it then assigning it before?

Comment: based on the title, sounds like you want a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`

Comment: I have no idea how I did that, I guess I pressed shift+enter to keep going on the code block one too many times, also did that really need a -1 instantly?

Comment: The `reset()` member function in both smart pointers @vu1p3n0x suggested will do exactly this (release the old object if there is one, reassign to a new address).  Also, it's safe to `delete` a null pointer, you don't have to test it yourself, the compiler will make sure to correctly handle null pointer values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`, then the memory managed by it will be kept alive or deleted as you'd expect.

If you assign to a `unique_ptr`, whatever memory it was managing would be deleted before assuming responsibility of the new memory.

Comment: Thank you I had no idea that even existed, side question, is using "raw" pointer a bad habit in c++, should I always use unique/shared from std:: from now?, nevermind, I just read the related question answeing that.

Comment: @A.albin depends. You may still need it in exotic cases, a) you need  your own memory manager, e.g. to pool your data or optimize it, though today a lot of those function are implemented in standard library. b) your platform (usually embedded) dictates preference for creation of  own library c) you have to interact with hardware-related APIs, deal with kernel functions, write kernel modules\drivers where you're not in control of objects life.

Comment: @A.albin in general, never use raw owning pointers (raw pointers that manage their pointee's lifetime via `new` and `delete`). Use smart pointers for lifetime management, and raw pointers or references for other indirections.